# Escape Code to Change Cursor Shape

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

I know that Konsole supports an escape code like `"\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"` that will change the cursor shape. I was wondering if any other terminal emulators support changing the cursor shape via an escape code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Linux VGA/framebuffer consoles use the [`Esc[?...c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/vga-softcursor.rst) code.

`xterm` supports the VT520 sequence DECSCUSR [`Esc[... q`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_) since patch 282.

Comment: CL: Do you know of anything else besides xterm supporting the VT520 escape codes?

Comment: One would think that other terminals would want to be compatible with `xterm`, but I haven't found any that document this.

Comment: https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/pull/92 mentions that MinTTY/TeraTerm/RLogin support this too.

Comment: I'd give my left nut for Terminal.app to support this on OS X.

Comment: Just in case this helps others: After compiling/using the [sanos](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/editor.htm) text editor in a remote console (which I was accessing over SSH), the cursor was changed to the block shape (`█`). Following this answer, I tried to restore the vertical line cursor (`|`, called "bar" in the xterm documentation linked above) with both `printf '\033[?5c'` and `printf '\033[5 q'`. The latter worked.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE Well I know it's been 10 years but Terminal.app does support the VT520 DECSCUSR sequence now.